# Truncating a string to certain length, and then adding characters to the end in C

Tags: c, string

If a string is greater than a certain length, I want to truncate it to a certain length, and replace the last 3 characters with a period ("."). What I have right now causes a segmentation fault:

```
#define NAME_LENGTH 36

name is of type, char*. 

if (strlen(name) > NAME_LENGTH){
    //we need to truncate the name
    printf("NAME IS TOO LONG.. TRUNCATING\n");
    char *nCpy = NULL; //the truncated name
    strncpy(nCpy, name, NAME_LENGTH); //copy NAME_LENGTH number of characters from name into nCpy
    printf("Truncated name, now adding ...\n");
    strcat(name, "..."); //append "..." to end of name
    printf("... added, now copying to struct\n");
    strcpy(record->name, nCpy); //assign our name in our record
    printf("NAME IS NOW: %s\n", record->name);
}
```

Upon running, if a name that is longer than NAME_LENGTH, I get a segmentation fault.

```
Enter name > jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
NAME IS TOO LONG.. TRUNCATING
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: strncpy doesn't allocate space.  This code is trying to copy a string to NULL.

Comment: `char *nCpy = NULL;` `strncpy(nCpy(NULL), name, NAME_LENGTH); `

Comment: `strcat(name, "...");` should be `strcat(nCpy, "...");`

Comment: I suppose strncpy(nCpy, name, NAME_LENGTH) should be strncpy(nCpy, name, NAME_LENGTH-3) because I am adding 3 more characters, and if I use NAME_LENGTH then the ending result will be a string of length 39.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are segfaulting because you didn't allocate memory to store where nCpy is pointing at.

```
char *nCpy = NULL; //the truncated name
```

Should be something like

```
char *nCpy = malloc(sizeof(char) * NAME_LENGTH + 1); //the truncated name
```

What you're trying now is to write to some junk value in memory, who knows, which almost always leads to a segmentation fault.

As Paul points out, you need to allocate space for NAME_LENGTH characters, plus one since a character string is null terminated with the special `/0` character.
This specific error is called [dereferencing a null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007268/what-exactly-is-meant-by-de-referencing-a-null-pointer)

Comment: You'll want to allocate `NAME_LENGTH + 1` chars; `strncpy()` won't null-terminate if it runs out of room.

Comment: @edwardmp, thanks for your suggestion. Is it appropriate to free(nCpy) once I have assigned it to record->name?

Comment: @FatalProphet yes I probably think you can free it after that line. But you'll notice it yourself when you play it with ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are really doing far too many string copies, and not freeing the copies afterwards, so you're going to end up with a lot of leaked memory. Also, it's not clear whether `record->name` is actually long enough to hold the returned string, but if it is, you might as well build the name in place.

Here's one possibility, which assumes that `record->name` already points to at least `NAME_LENGTH + 1` bytes of storage:

```
if (strlen(name) > NAME_LENGTH)
  snprintf(record->name, NAME_LENGTH + 1, "%.*s...", NAME_LENGTH - 3, name);
else
  strncpy(record->name, name, NAME_LENGTH + 1);
```

Here's another, possibly simpler or possibly more mysterious way of doing it:

```
if (snprintf(record->name, NAME_LENGTH + 1, "%s", name) > NAME_LENGTH))
  strcpy(record->name + NAME_LENGTH - 3, "...");
```