# C - Longest subarray of specified elements from given array

Tags: c, function-pointers, sub-array

I need help with the following problem:

Given an array `arr` of `structs`

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    float amount,price;
}product;
```

Print the longest subarray of elements from array `arr` such that the `arr` element has greater or equal `price` than some `value` which is read.

Function to check if element has greater or equal `price` than a `value` is given as an argument of a function `void subarray(product *arr,int n,int (*check)(product * ,float ),
        product *newArr,int *len_newArr,float value)`
where `newArr` is the output subarray.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    float amount,price;
}product;

void subarray(product *arr,int n,int (*check)(product * ,float ),
                product *newArr,int *len_newArr,float value)
{
    len_newArr=0;
    int *current_len;
    current_len=0;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        //if condition is true, increment current length of newArr
        //and store that element to newArr
        if((*check)(arr+i,value))
        {
            current_len++;
            newArr[i]=arr[i];
        }
        else
            //begin with the next subarray
            current_len=1;

        //update newArr length
        if(current_len > len_newArr)
            len_newArr=current_len;
    }

    newArr=calloc(*len_newArr , sizeof(product));

    //print the subarray
    for(i=0;i<len_newArr;i++)
        printf("%-19s %6.2f %6.2f\n",newArr[i].name,newArr[i].amount,newArr[i].price);
}

int check(product *pr,float value)
{
    if(pr->price >= value)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void inputProduct(product *pr)
{
    printf("name: ");
    scanf("%s",pr->name);
    printf("amount: ");
    scanf("%f",&pr->amount);
    printf("price: ");
    scanf("%f",&pr->price);
}

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    product *arr,*newArr;
    int len_newArr;
    float value;

    do
    {
        printf("n = ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    while(n<1);

    arr=malloc(n * sizeof(product));
    newArr=calloc(n,sizeof(product));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. product: \n",i+1);
        inputProduct(arr+i);
    }

    printf("value: ");
    scanf("%f",&value);

    subarray(arr,n,&check,newArr,&len_newArr,value);

    return 0;
}
```

The program gives warnings `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast` at line

```
    //begin with the next subarray
    current_len=1;
```

and `comparison between pointer and integer` at line

```
//print the subarray
for(i=0;i<len_newArr;i++)
    printf("%-19s %6.2f %6.2f\n",newArr[i].name,newArr[i].amount,newArr[i].price);
```

Comment: Why do you declare `current_len` as a pointer? And what do you think initializing this pointer to `0` does?

Comment: I also don't see why you pass `newArr` and `len_newArr` as arguments to the function? They are not used outside the `subarray` function. And *if* you use `newArr` outside the function you need to pass a pointer to the pointer (i.e. `product **`) to the function.

Comment: Finally, you allocate memory for `newArr` in the `subarray` function, but you never initialize it before you print the contents of it. Lots and lots and lots of things that does (or could) lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *current_len=0; /* assigining NULL to a pointer to int */
```

This

```
        *current_len++;
```

Is equivalent to `*NULL++` and you can not dereference a pointer to `NULL`. [[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4007268/1606345)]

Same here:

```
*current_len=1;
```

It seems that you want a plain `int` instead of a pointer to `int`