# Error while using getopt

Tags: c, arguments, getopt, getopt-long

When i pass any argument i get this error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
only -h option works properly.

Here option -d and -a takes string value.
option -s and -e takes integer value.

how can i save the values of options passed to a different variable for later usage ?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

void usage() {
    printf("Usage: help\n----------\n------");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int opt= 0;
    int start = -1, end = -1;
    char *alg,*dir;

    static struct option long_options[] = {
        {"start",no_argument,0,'s' },
        {"end",no_argument,0,'e' },
        {"algorithm",no_argument, 0,'a' },
        {"directory",required_argument, 0,'d' },
        {0,0,0,0}
    };

    int long_index =0;
    while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv,"seadh:",
               long_options, &long_index )) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
          case 'a' :
            printf("you entered \"%s\"\n", optarg); // error while printing this
            break;
          case 'd' :
            printf("you entered \"%s\"\n", optarg);
            break;
          case 's' : start = atoi(optarg);
            break;
          case 'e' : end = atoi(optarg);
            break;
          case 'h' : usage();
            break;
          default: usage();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    printf("%d",start);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to use the options passed along with their values to call a python script inside this C program using system Call .

eg :  system(python alg.py -alr -s3 -e45 -d/path)

Comment: `{"algorithm",no_argument, 0,'a' }` --> `{"algorithm",required_argument, 0,'a' }` (same as `s`, `e` ) and `"seadh:"` --> `"s:e:a:d:h"`

Comment: Wait...you actually need argument for "help", not the other way round?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  "s:e:a:d:h" this is working , but how do i save this options values to different variable ? My main requirement is to send this to options to python script called with in c program .    Read the end part of question after the code ,  how can i do that ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY     {"algorithm",no_argument, 0,'a' } --> {"algorithm",required_argument, 0,'a' }   ,   option a, s and e are optional , only -d option is a must ,  so do i need to still make all others as required_argument ?

Comment: @programmer `required_argument` means that the option needs an argument, not that the option is mandatory.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck but this code is working fine , and accepting arguments even if i have specified no_arguments .

Comment: @programmer I choose to believe the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `getopt_long()` is

```
int getopt_long(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring, const struct option *longopts, int *longindex);
```

The characters in `optstring` are short options. If a short option name is followed by colon (`:`), that option always needs an argument. As in the case of short option `e` in an `optstring` like `"ae:d"`.

If there are two colons as the case of `y` in `"ae:y::f"`, the short option's argument is optional.

If there is no colon after a short option character in `optstring`, it means that the option never takes an argument.

So, in your case, the `optstring` should be `a:d:e:s:h`

`optarg` points to the argument of the option only if the option has one. Otherwise it will be `(null)`.

And dereferencing a `NULL` invokes undefined behaviour. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007268/what-exactly-is-meant-by-de-referencing-a-null-pointer).

The short options you need are `a`, `d`, `e` and `s` all of which can take argument. I'm assuming that they always take an argument. Change it to optional argument if that's what you want.

We obtain the argument via `optarg` which will point to the argument string. If you need the argument as a number, you must convert the string to number. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7021725/5375464) post for conversion to integer.

Since all your options need arguments, the `has_arg` field of the `struct option` should be `required_argument` instead of `no_argument`. If the argument is optional, make it `optional_argument'.

```
static struct option long_options[] = {
    {"start", required_argument,0,'s' },
    {"end", required_argument,0,'e' },
    {"algorithm", required_argument, 0,'a' },
    {"directory",required_argument, 0,'d' },
};
```

So the loop could be like

```
int c, longindex=0, n;
while( (c=getopt_long(argc, argv, "a:e:d:s:h", long_options, &longindex ))!=-1 )
{
    switch(c)
    {
    case 'a':
        fprintf(stdout, "\na value: %s", optarg);
        break;
    case 'e':
        n=strtol(optarg, NULL, 10);
        fprintf(stdout, "\ne value: %d", n);
        break;
    case 'd':
        fprintf(stdout, "\nd value: %s", optarg);
        break;
    case 's':
        n=strtol(optarg, NULL, 10);
        fprintf(stdout, "\ns value: %d", n);
        break;
    case 'h':
        printf("\nh found.");
        break;
    }
}
```

I have not done the error checking after [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) for brevity, you should handle that.

You should take care of problems like unknown flags, duplicate flags, extra arguments, etc as well. Check the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) of getopt.