# Binary Search in C - Stuck in a loop

Tags: c, sorting, infinite-loop

I'm currently trying to write a program which takes an array of numbers and sorts them into a new array using a binary search method. Right now, I'm stuck in an infinite loop because: `if( &arr[mid_val] != NULL)` keeps returning true, even though I've initialized `int *arr` as `NULL` .

Why is this the case? Should it not return false on the first iteration?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int binary_search( int *arr, int to_find, int size ) {
    int mid_val;
    int new_size;
    int return_val;
    int *new_arr;

    mid_val = size / 2;

    printf("infinite\n");

    if( &arr[mid_val] != NULL ) {    /* why does this return true in the first iteration? */
        if( to_find > arr[mid_val] ) {
            /* second half of arr */
            new_arr = malloc( sizeof( int ) * ( mid_val ) );
            memcpy( new_arr, &arr[mid_val], sizeof( int ) * ( mid_val ) );
            new_size = mid_val;

            return_val = mid_val + binary_search( new_arr, to_find, new_size );

            return return_val;
        }
        else if( to_find < arr[mid_val] ) {
            /* first half of arr */
            new_arr = malloc( sizeof( int ) * ( mid_val ) );
            memcpy( new_arr, arr, sizeof( int ) * ( mid_val ) );
            new_size = mid_val;

            return_val = binary_search( new_arr, to_find, new_size );

            return return_val;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main ( ) {
    int i;
    int pos;
    int size = 0;
    int numbers[10] = { 5, 8, 12, 2, 1, 0, 9, 22, 21, 55 };
    int *arr = NULL;

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr = realloc( arr, sizeof( int ) * ( size + 1 ) );

        pos = binary_search( arr, numbers[i], size );

        memcpy( &arr[pos + 1], &arr[pos], ( size - pos ) * sizeof( int ) );
        memcpy( &arr[pos], &numbers[i], sizeof( int ) );

        size++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @lurker Sorry, that was meant to be `&arr[mid_val] != NULL`. The purpose of that statement is supposed to be so that when `arr` is not yet populated, (the first call to `binary_search`) , it will return 0 and place the first number at `arr[0]`.

Comment: Even though `arr` isn't populated, `arr` still represents a valid address for your array of numbers. If `arr` is a valid address and `mid_val` is a valid offset to that address, how could `&arr[mid_val]` (which is the same as `arr + mid_val`) ever possibly be NULL? So of course `&arr[mid_val] != NULL` is always true.

Comment: Another problem I see here is that binary search works only with sorted arrays, your array is not sorted, the binary search algorithm doesn't make sense if the array is not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You are leaking memory like a broken water pipe.

```
if( &arr[mid_val] != NULL ) {    /* why does this return true in the first iteration? */
```

This is always true, except when `mid_val` is 0 and `arr` is `NULL`.
The expression `arr[mid_val]` is equivalent to `arr + mid_val`, which when
`mid_val` is not 0 will return you the address where `arr` pointing **plus** the
offset `mid_val * sizeof(*arr)`.

What you have to do is first check that `arr` is not `NULL`. If it is `NULL`
then return an error value.

```
int binary_search( int *arr, int to_find, int size ) {
    ...

    if(arr == NULL)
        return -1;  // negative index == error
}
```

In this block:

```
new_arr = malloc( sizeof( int ) * ( mid_val ) );
memcpy( new_arr, &arr[mid_val], sizeof( int ) * ( mid_val ) );
new_size = mid_val;

return_val = mid_val + binary_search( new_arr, to_find, new_size );

return return_val;
```

you are allocating memory for the copy of the array of half size. But you never
free the memory, that's where your code is leaking. You should do:

```
return_val = mid_val + binary_search( new_arr, to_find, new_size );

free(new_arr);
return return_val;
```

If your search does not find anything, you should return -1. 0 is a valid index,
how can you distinguish between and error and a valid index?

Also you don't have a real terminal case for the iteration, eventually `mid_val`
will reach 0 and you will keep calling `malloc` with size 0. The recursion will
only end when `malloc` returns `NULL` or you've reached the limits of recursion.
In both cases you've consumed so much resources, that
the system kills your program or it ends in a segfault.

Note that `malloc(0)` does not necessarily return `NULL`.

> *man malloc*
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> void *malloc(size_t size);
> ```
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The `malloc()` and `calloc()` functions return a pointer to the allocated memory, which is suitably aligned  for  any  built-in  type.
>   On error, these functions return `NULL`.  `NULL` **may** also be returned by a successful call to `malloc()` with a size of zero, or by a successful
>   call to `calloc()` with `nmemb` or `size` equal to zero.

It says *may*, not *will*. Other sources say:

> http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html
>
> The pointer returned points to the start (lowest byte address) of the allocated space. If the space cannot be allocated, a null pointer shall be returned. **If the size of the space requested is 0, the behavior is implementation-defined: the value returned shall be either a null pointer or a unique pointer.**

In any case, you cannot relay for a terminal case that `malloc` returns `NULL`
when you request 0 bytes.

But the biggest problem of all in your code is that the [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) algorithm is design to work on
sorted arrays. If the array is not sorted, then searching only in the space
before/after the mid-element makes no sense, as there would be no guarantee that
all element after the mid-element are larger and all elements before the
mid-element are respectively smaller. Your initial array is not sorted, binary
search is pointless.

I think that using `malloc` for a binary search is quite a waste of resources,
all you need is to pass the start and end of the search space. This is a
possible implementation of the binary search, note that the array is sorted to
begin with. There are tons of example implementations of this on the internet, a
simple Google search shows in the first page some version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int binary_search(int *arr, int to_find, size_t start, size_t end)
{
    if(arr == NULL)
        return -1;

    if(start == end)
    {
        if(arr[start] == to_find)
            return start;

        return -1; // not found
    }


    int index;
    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

    if(arr[mid] == to_find)
        return mid;

    if(to_find < arr[mid])
        index = binary_search(arr, to_find, start, mid - 1);
    else
        index = binary_search(arr, to_find, mid + 1, end);

    return index;
}


int main(void)
{
    int numbers[] = { -19, -17, -3, 0, 5, 9, 12, 13, 14, 18, 20, 44, 77, 122, 888 };

    size_t arrlen = sizeof numbers / sizeof *numbers;

    int index;
    int search[] = { -19, -17, -3, 0, 5, 9, 12, 13, 14, 18, 20, 44, 77, 122, 888, 32, 50 };

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof search / sizeof *search; ++i)
    {
        index = binary_search(numbers, search[i], 0, arrlen - 1);

        if(index == -1)
            printf("Number %d not found\n", search[i]);
        else
            printf("Number %d found at index: %d\n", search[i], index);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Number -19 found at index: 0
Number -17 found at index: 1
Number -3 found at index: 2
Number 0 found at index: 3
Number 5 found at index: 4
Number 9 found at index: 5
Number 12 found at index: 6
Number 13 found at index: 7
Number 14 found at index: 8
Number 18 found at index: 9
Number 20 found at index: 10
Number 44 found at index: 11
Number 77 found at index: 12
Number 122 found at index: 13
Number 888 found at index: 14
Number 32 not found
Number 50 not found
```

Answer (score 0):

> if( arr[mid_val] != NULL) keeps returning true, even though I've initialized int *arr as NULL

If `arr` is NULL, you are [dereferencing a null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007268/what-exactly-is-meant-by-de-referencing-a-null-pointer). You need to allocate memory for `arr` to point to and initialize the contents of that memory.

Note that `int *arr` represents the array you want to search. If it is null, you have nothing to search.

You may have meant to say that you allocated memory for `arr` and filled the memory with something... zero's? Filling it with NULL doesn't make sense. As @lurker pointed out in the comments, comparing an integer to NULL likely isn't what you intend.

Comment: I think the OP means that `*arr` is `NULL` before the `realloc` call.

Comment: @EricJ Sorry, that was meant to be `&arr[mid_val] != NULL`. The purpose of that statement is supposed to be so that when `arr` is not yet populated, (the first call to `binary_search`) , it will return 0 and place the first number at `arr[0]`. Is there a different statement I can use to achieve that effect?

Comment: @PMac this statement makes no sense, because `arr` is a single pointer, it is either `NULL` or not `NULL`.  If `arr` is not `NULL`, `&arr[mid_val]` can never be `NULL`, because `arr[mid_val]` is the same as `arr + mid_val`. You have to check `if(arr == NULL)` before doing anything and leaving the function when `arr` is `NULL`.