# If a pointer to pointer is NULL, then is it necessary that the pointer is also NULL?

Tags: c, pointers, null

Consider I have a structure

```
typedef struct point_t
{
  int x;
  int y;
}POINT;
```

I create a pointer to pointer for POINT and initialize it to `NULL`.

```
POINT **ppPoint = NULL;
```

Should `*ppPoint` also return `NULL` ?

Comment: You can't dereference a null pointer, therefore `*ppPoint` is invalid.

Comment: A pointer to a pointer follows the same rules as all other pointers.

Comment: @Bathsheba, can you state the reason to reopen this post? I closed as a duplicate of [What EXACTLY is meant by “de-referencing a NULL pointer”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007268/what-exactly-is-meant-by-de-referencing-a-null-pointer) -- because -- A pointer whether it's double pointer, triple pointer or quad pointer -- is a pointer. The rules apply on them in the same way. Would you reopen the questions, if someone asks the same as above for *N-th* pointer?

Comment: @iammilind: It's a linked question, not a duplicate.

Comment: Well, if one understands that a pointer-to-pointer isn't a special case, then it is kind of a dupe question. But that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 11):

The fact that there are 2 layers of pointers here is actually irrelevant. The fact that your outer pointer in `NULL` means it is **illegal** to dereference it. Therefore it is not meaningful to ask what value you would get by dereferencing it.

Consider this:

```
int *p = NULL; // modern practice would be to use nullptr anyway

if (0 == *p) // this is Undefined Behaviour!
{
    // do something, maybe?
}
```

You are just adding another layer to this, where instead of `int`, you have `point_t*`, but it really makes no difference.

The thing with [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is that **anything can happen**! Your program might crash, or it might **appear** to work, or it might give you garbage values sometimes, or it might ...

Comment: Nitpick, comment should be `// Behavior undefined, this is!`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't dereference a pointer which has a value of `NULL`. So you won't be able to access `*ppPoint`.

You can check the address of a variable with the `%p` formater in a `printf()` to check.

```
printf("Address of ppPoint: %p", *ppPoint);
printf("Address of *ppPoint: %p", *ppPoint);
```

Answer (score 3):

A null pointer does not point to *anything*. That applies to ordinary pointers, function pointers and member pointers alike. It also applies to pointers to pointers.

Therefore, it doesn't make sense to talk about the value of "what it points to".

Answer (score 3):

First, there's the usual misconceptions about the mysterious null. In this case there's 3 related terms:

- *null pointer*
- *null pointer constant*
- The `NULL` macro

A null pointer constant is the integer `0` or that integer cast to a pointer, `(void*)0`. The `NULL` macro is guaranteed to be a portable null pointer constant.

Whenever you assign a null pointer constant, such as `NULL`, to any pointer, that pointer becomes a *null pointer*. This allows compilers to internally represent a null pointer as something else than `0`, because the address `0x00...00` is quite often a valid physical address on many systems.

Specifically, C17 6.3.2.3/3 defines this:

> An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type
>   `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

---

When accessing a null pointer by de-referencing it, with don't get any predictable result. This is undefined behavior as per C17 6.5.3.2/4:

> If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined.

Meaning anything can happen. If you are lucky, you just get a system crash.

You can however compare a null pointer against another null pointer, or against a null pointer constant, and they are guaranteed to be equal (C17 6.5.9).

As for pointer-to-pointer being some a special case, it is not. The pointed-at type is irrelevant for any of the above mentioned rules. Overall there is nothing special with pointer-to-pointer in C - it is never a special case, but always to be regarded as pointer-to-type.