# Why can't one print NULL in c program?

Tags: c

In the following program, i am getting a runtime error instead of my program printing NULL. May be this is very silly or simple understanding but i do not have right answer. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
   char *p = NULL;
   printf("%c", *p);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%c` is for printing a character, not NULL.

Comment: The runtime error is because you are dereferencing a null pointer

Comment: You mean `printf("%s", p);`? (its behavior [depends on environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589342/what-is-the-behavior-of-printing-null-with-printfs-s-specifier))

Comment: @MikeCAT `*p` is not `NULL` (is garbage)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What EXACTLY is meant by "de-referencing a NULL pointer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007268/what-exactly-is-meant-by-de-referencing-a-null-pointer)

Comment: @ArdentCoder Yes, got it. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("%c", *p);` does not ask `printf` to print the value `NULL`. It attempts to use the value pointed to by `p`. Since `p` contains a null pointer, it does not point to a valid object.

To print the value of `p`, use `printf("%p", (void *) p);`.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't catch you trying to de-reference a null pointer.

If you want to see the value of the pointer (and see whether the pointer is null), use this printf syntax:

```
   printf("%p\n", p);
```

Comment: `printf("%p\n", (void*)p);` is better to avoid invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @MikeCAT can you provide a reference to why using `char*` instead `void*` results in undefined behaviour?

Comment: [c - printf("%p") and casting to (void *) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/printfp-and-casting-to-void)

Comment: @MikeCAT please see [C11 § 6.2.5 ¶ 28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28): _A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type_, and its footnote _The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions_.