# Why passing pointer to a function lead to a Runtime Error?

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error

I'm trying to understand how passing pointers to functions work, but I don't understand the following situation :
Why this code work

```
void setVar(uint32_t* var) {
    *var = 10;
} 

int main() {
    uint32_t myVar = 0;
    setVar(&myVar);

    return 0;
}
```

and this one lead to a runtime error ? :

```
void setVar(uint32_t* var) {
    *var = 10;
} 

int main() {
    uint32_t* myVar = 0;
    setVar(myVar);

    return 0;
}
```

I'd appreciate your answers.

Comment: Because you dereference a null pointer. Also you no allocated memory for the the function to write in.

Comment: That is because `uint32_t* myVar = 0;` initializes `myVar` to `NULL`, not `* myVar`

Comment: since you are initializing uint32_t pointer (myVar) to 0 you are saying that you store memory address into myVar and when you dereference it you you are trying to set memory  address 0 to 10 what you want to do is ```uint32_t myVar = 10;uint32_t* pointer = &myVar;``` and pass pointer to your function

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean

Comment: Ask yourself this question: where does `myVar` point?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk/2094715#2094715

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What EXACTLY is meant by "de-referencing a NULL pointer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007268/what-exactly-is-meant-by-de-referencing-a-null-pointer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the pointer.
The issue is that you initialize the pointer you pass to the function with 0 (`uint32_t* myVar = 0;`) and then dereference it in your function (`*var = 10;`), which is disallowed.
You should make sure, the pointer that is passed is not a `NULL` pointer, either do that within the function or make sure that function only ever is called with valid parameters.