# What is the Difference between accessing a Pointer whose value is Null and accessing what it points to?

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior

- I've heard that accessing a pointer whose value is null is safe since you are not setting any data to it or from it, you are just accessing it.
- But I also heard that accessing what it points to (when it's null) isn't safe, why is that?
- If you are accessing to what it points to (when it's null) aren't you accessing nothing?
- I think that there shouldn't be any issues with that unless you are setting values to something from it.
- I've heard that from many people tho I never experienced any crashes or bugs related to that (when reading data from inside a pointer that is null), when I catch an exception I just let it be since I'm not setting any data from it to something. Is that ok?

```cpp
int x; 
int* px = &x; 
int* pn = nullptr; 
if (px==px) { do something;}
```

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing"? Like reading its value (e.g. `int* ptr = nullptr; std::cout << ptr;`)? Or *dereferencing* the pointer (e.g. `int* ptr = nullptr; std::cout << *ptr;`)?

Comment: Also, possible crashes from invalid pointer dereference (which aren't guaranteed to happen!) aren't thrown as C++ exceptions, you can't catch them in that way.

Comment: Invalid pointer dereferences _might be_ thrown as exceptions, undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude By accessing I mean dereferencing

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009070/12002570): *"Dereferencing just means accessing the memory value at a given address."*

Comment: In that case I don't understand what you think is the difference between "accessing a pointer whose value is null" (which you think is safe) and "accessing what it points to" (which isn't).

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer does not try to access *nothing*, it tries to access *something* that is *nowhere*.

Comment: I think with "accessing a pointer" you mean dereferecing it, e.g. `Foo &foo = *fooPtr;` and with "accessing what it points to"  you mean accessing properties of the referenced value, e.g. `std::cout << fooPtr->someMember;`? Is that right?

Comment: @churill exactly, that is what I meant.

Comment: The "arrow" syntax is really syntactic sugar for plain dereference with the `*` operator. E.g. `fooPtr->someMember` is equivalent to `(*fooPtr).someMember`. In both cases there's a dereference, which is "accessing what it points to". And that is UB for null or otherwise invalid pointers.

Comment: _I've heard that accessing a pointer whose value is null is safe_ Whoever told you this doesn't know the stuff. I would check twice what this person told you else... :-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Former System Engineer Then IT Architect at IBM (company) told me that.

Comment: @OskarKierakowicz I am pretty sure either you have misinterpreted his(architect at ibm) statement or misheard him, assuming he/she was talking about C++ in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure he was talking about C++? When I worked on SGI / Irix in the past, the access to null pointers wasn't valid as well (of course) but it didn't result in a crash like I was used on a PC. Guess how surprised I was when I compiled this software for PC/Linux. It already crashed before even reaching `main()`. That was a hard lesson but  a valuable... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat you are right, he spoke about C and not C++ my bad, Sorry.
If it really causes the software/program/dll to have Undefined behavior then the conversation is over, thanks everyone.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. To dereference a null pointer is Undefined Behavior in C as well. (I guess C++ inherited this behavior from C.) The [cppreference doc. for C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) does mention it explicitly. In the [C++ doc.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_indirection_operator), I missed this detail somehow (or overlooked it).

Comment: @molbdnilo _"access something that is nowhere."_ That's quite poetic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code (as it's exposed by OP in this moment) got a bit confusing.

Thus, I would like to add some examples to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72314185/7478597) what's allowed and what not:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x = 0; // make some storage
  int* px = &x; // px initalized with address of x     -> OK.
  int* pn = nullptr; // pn initialized with nullptr    -> OK.
  if (px == px) { /* ... */ } // senseless but         -> OK.
  if (px == pn) { /* ... */ } //                       -> OK.
  std::cout << *px; // dereference a valid pointer     -> OK.
  std::cout << *pn; // dereference a null pointer      -> UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR!
  px = pn; // assign a (null) pointer                  -> OK.
  std::cout << *px; // dereference a null pointer      -> UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR!
  // ...and finally a common bug...
  int* py = nullptr; //                                -> OK.
  { int y = 1; // storage with limited life-time       -> OK.
    py = &y; // assign address of storage              -> OK.
  } // scope end -> life-time of y ends                -> OK.
  // Attention! This makes py dangling (pointing to released storage).
  if (py /* != nullptr*/) { // This doesn't help. py is not a null pointer.
    std::cout << *py; // access after end of life-time -> UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR!
  }
}
```

Output of Compiler (g++ 11.2):

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp # && ./a.out # Compile but don't exec. It contains UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR!
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:8:10: warning: self-comparison always evaluates to true [-Wtautological-compare]
    8 |   if (px == px) { /* ... */ } // senseless but         -> OK.
      |       ~~ ^~ ~~
```

[Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/075ec3c3870a4154)

Answer (score 1):

> By accessing I mean dereferencing

Dereferencing a null pointer is **undefined behavior**.

> I never experienced any crashes or bugs related to that

The program has **undefined behavior** meaning it is still in error even if it doesn't say so explicitly and "seems to be working".

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior. The program may just crash.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>